# "operating system not found " after installing ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot-repair

I successful installed ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop with USB key. But after I reboot I get this error "operating system not found"

I used boot-repair and it gives me this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6618963/

I think I probably messed up with the partitioning.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Which drive did you set your bios to boot from?  Make sure it is set to boot from the correct drive.

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, I think you do not have a boot loader. The boot loader directs you to your operating system. You must have a boot loader if you are doing dual boot. If you are not dual booting, then don't bother reading this. Please give more information.

Comment: His logs clearly show grub is installed on sdb...

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have 3 HDD in your system. At the moment of the installation the configuration/setting was done wrong. Are you dual-booting? If not (and if you don't mind to erase your data) I'd suggest to make a new, clean install with proper attention to HDD designation (sda, sdb, sdc, etc...)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. My computer is not dual-booting and I already erased my data. I every time I install ubuntu I chose to erase the previously installed OS. And I install the new OS in sdb, which I think is the primary HDD, while sda is my USB key. Can u give me more instructions?

Comment: unplug your USB key. It seems that you have yet another HDD -sdc-, unplug it too if possible, due to the fact that i don't know too well how to handle partitions. After you unplug these 2 drives then begin with the install.